# Squid + Dansguardian Google instant filtering

Tags: linux, proxy, squid, internet-filter

I have a proxy setup using squid with dansguardian for filtering. Everything is working fine but Google instant and images.

I find that dansguardian is no longer able to force safe search. It seems to me from my searching on the internet that Google has done some upgrades to their services but dansguard has fallen behind.

I can't find anything else for free that will accomplish what I have set out to do; web filtering (porn, unsafe school content, etc) on a linux system.

Is there anything I can do to dansguardian (config wise) or another application I can use?